# php exec or system start up command line app and keep it alive

Tags: php, exec, shell-exec

I'm trying start a command line SIP user agent from php.

`exec()` and `system()` starting it but when it finishes the startup and should enter in a "listening" state it simply quits without error.

Is it possible start an app and keep it running.

Oh I'm trying do this on debian with php7.

**EDIT**

[I copied the output of system() to pastebin](https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/cD8uicSf)

In this there is one line suspicous for me, whitch is this: `Cannot switch back to console from file redirection` I dont see this if I run the app from terminal

Comment: Why are you starting it from PHP? Is there something stopping you from starting it in the same way you run PHP on boot?

Comment: Without any example code I cannot determine what is going on. So it quits without error, well. Do we take your word for that?

Comment: If you use `exec()` it should hang until the program has exited unless your buffering your output to a file or some other stream.

Comment: I pasted the output of system() on pastebin this is exactly the same what is logged into local log on my machine. exec() only returns the last line of it